# Calling a lengthy Service method from an Activity - Best Practice

Tags: android, multithreading, android-asynctask

I'm developing an app with a service that forwards calls to a web-service, and a few activities that place those calls. The activities need to process the results of those calls. For example, I have a writeComment method on the service, that accesses the web-service and returns some information about the newly written comment.

Right now I let the Activity take care of all the threading. The Activity binds the service, and then uses an AsyncTask that calls the bound service's writeComment method.

All works well as long as the Activity isn't stopped while the AsyncTask is running. If it does (easily happens when flipping the phone), the AsyncTask dies a violent death when trying to update the UI in onPostExecute. I'm not entirely sure how to fix this - I *do* need to let the user know the server has been updated.

If I go the other way around, and register a callback with the Service, I'm still a bit stump, because I need to notify the Service the Activity has changed - I need to tell it not to notify me in the first Activity's onDestory, and reregister in the second Activity's onCreate. And I need to handle the case where the asynchronous task completes after onDestroy and before onCreate.

What is considered Best Practice in this case?

Thanks,
  Itay.

Answer (score 1):

My intuition tells me to let the service handle the threading. Services are far less transient (although still transient to some degree) than activities and therefore you'll have less issues of threads trying to interact with a Context (be it an Activity or a Service) that's no longer there. Have you looked at the [IntentService](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/IntentService.html) class? It handles a lot of the threading for you.

Comment: IntentService indeed handles the threading, but it doesn't handle callbacks.

Answer (score 1):

In my app, I have a long-running service and Activities that need to render data in the service.  The service also pings the Activities when there is a change but the Activity can also query the service.  The way I approached this was two-fold.

Firstly, I bind my activity to the Service in order to send messages from Activity to service.

Secondly, the Service sends notifications with Broadcasts and the Activity listens for those broadcasts.  I set that up in the Activity onResume and tear it down in the onPause.  I think this is the part that you're missing.

Comment: Yes, it might be. I'll have to toy with this for a while. I'm really unhappy with AsyncTask, seems like it's only good for tasks you don't really care about.